# What is the best join condition for this two scenarios

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables that i am trying to join to come up with the data that i need to report on.

- First table contains  all the interns that company hired.
- Second table contain all the full the people that were interns but have been hired into full time position.

Requirement is to pull data that shows all the hired interns and out of those interns, get a count of all the ones that we hired into full time  position.

Problem is when I do inner join I am only getting interns that were hired into full time position and not all the interns that were hired irrespective of whether they transitioned to full time or not.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is to use outer join (instead of inner join).

Here's an example: sample tables:

```
SQL> create table t_first
  2    (id   number,
  3     name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table t_second
  2    (id   number,
  3     name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t_first (id, name)
  2    select 1, 'Little' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Foot'   from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'Scott'  from dual union all
  5    select 4, 'Tiger'  from dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> insert into t_second (id, name)
  2    select 3, 'Scott'  from dual union all
  3    select 4, 'Tiger'  from dual;

2 rows created.
```

Select all of them, distinguish those who were hired to full time position:

```
SQL> select h.id, h.name,
  2    decode(f.id, null, 'No', 'Yes') full_time_position
  3  from t_first h left join t_second f on h.id = f.id
  4  order by h.id;

        ID NAME                 FUL
---------- -------------------- ---
         1 Little               No
         2 Foot                 No
         3 Scott                Yes
         4 Tiger                Yes

SQL>
```

I'm not sure what you meant by "counting" those who were hired to full time position. Where would you want to display that information? How? If you could provide an example, it would be easier to suggest a solution.